# Making a simple calculator python

Tags: python, calculator

I'd like to make a simple calculator that only takes in one line and includes only an integer, symbol, and another symbol.

It should support addition, subtract, multiplication, division, and mod.

If there are any spaces in between, decimals, words/letters it has to come out as “invalid input”.

Examples:

```
input: 5+5
output: 10

input: ten minus five
output: Invalid Input.

input: 4.5+2
output: Invalid Input.

input: 5 + 5
output: Invalid Input.
```

The issue is that when I type in the math problem (ie. 5+5) nothing comes out, it's just blank.  does anyone know how to fix this?

this is what I have so far:

```
o = "+","-","*","/","%"
x = input("Enter a math problem: ")

if " " in x:
  print("Invalid input")
  try: 
    num1,o,num2 = x.split()
  except ValueError: 
    print("Invalid Input")
    try: 
      num1 = int(num1)
      num2 = int(num2)
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid Input")
    if o not in x:
      print("Invalid Input")

if o == "+":
  r = int(num1) + int(num2)
elif o == "-":
  r = int(num1) - int(num2)
elif o == "*":
  r = int(num1) * int(num2)
elif o == "/":
  r = int(num1) / int(num2)
elif o == "%":
  r = int(num1) % int(num2)
  print("Result is", r)
```

Comment: Please clarify or correct the requirement "integer, symbol and another symbol.". In your valid example `5+5`, the first is an integer, the second a symbol (out of 5 operators) which determines the function as addition, the third: another symbol or rather another integer?

Answer (score 2):

#### Nothing coming out is correct

The "Result is" line is only printed if the *final* if is true. Did you mean to out-dent it?

#### Your splitting is incorrect

Have a look at this:

```
num1,o,num2 = x.split()
```

Do you realise you are overwriting the value of `o`?

#### Just printing "invalid input" is not enough

You need to stop onward processing. It would be better to raise a ValueError, and to be more specific about the error when you can.

#### You are doing more `int`ing than needed

Once is enough for each num.

#### Proposal

A quick hack may be the following:

```
operators = ["+","-","*","/","%"]
x = input("Enter a math problem: ")

if " " in x:
  raise ValueError("Invalid input - contains a space")

for operator in operators:
     if operator in x:
        num1,num2 = x.replace(operator," ").split()
        break
     raise ValueError("Invalid Input - no valid operator")

# let the invalid inputs raise their own Value errors (and stop onward processing)
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)

if operator == "+":
    r = num1 + num2
elif operator == "-":
    r = num1-num2
elif operator == "*":
    r = num1*num2
elif operator == "/":
    r = num1/num2
elif operator == "%":
    r = num1%num2

print("Result is", r)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have received some answers whilst I was testing your program and doing some refactoring.  Along with the previous good answers, I will present the following refactored code to also consider.

```
o = "+","-","*","/","%"

while True:                                                 # Provide a robust loop to allow entry of multiple calculations

    x = input("Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: ")      # Will exit when the user enters "q"

    if x == 'q':
        break;

    if " " not in x:                                        # Utilize a space that will be used in the splitting of the operands and operation
        print("Invalid input - need a space")
        continue

    try: 
        num1,o,num2 = x.split(" ")                          # Split using the space as the separator
    except ValueError: 
       print("Invalid input on split")
       continue

    try:
        num1 = int(num1)
        num2 = int(num2)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input - operands need to be integers")
        continue

    if o not in x:
        print("Invalid Input - operator was not found")
        continue

    if o == "+":
        r = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif o == "-":
        r = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif o == "*":
        r = int(num1) * int(num2)
    elif o == "/":
        r = int(num1) / int(num2)
    else:
        r = int(num1) % int(num2)

    print("Result is", r)
```

Here are some of the key points.

- To make the program a bit more robust, a "while" loop was added to allow for multiple equations to be evaluated by the user.
- As noted in one of the other answers, this version utilizes a space between the operands and the operator in order to make the split function work as needed.
- And, to make the program a bit more user friendly, the error messages were made a bit more verbose so to provide the user with a bit more information as to the issue that may have arisen with their input.

With those tweaks, following is some sample terminal output.

```
@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Calculator$ python3 Calc.py 
Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: 4+5
Invalid input - need a space
Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: 44.5 * 4
Invalid Input - operands need to be integers
Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: 4 + 5
Result is 9
Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: 211 / 4
Result is 52.75
Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: 323 % 3
Result is 2
Enter a math problem or 'q' to quit: q
```

You might give this version a try along with the other good suggestions and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: `while True:` is prone to infinite loop and dangerous because no clear exit-condition like `while x not in ['q','Q']:`. Why exactly is a loop allowing for multiple equations more robust (in terms of [robustness](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/blog/tactics-and-patterns-for-software-robustness/) as non-functional software-quality attribute) ?

Comment: Upvote for improved error-handling and [error-tolerant design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-tolerant_design) like explained in [UX Guidelines for Error Handling](https://www.userjourneys.com/blog/ux-guidelines-for-error-handling/) .. help the user to get their (math) problem expressed (incl. correcting their input) and finally solved.

Comment: Good point on the while loop usage.  The robustness inference was about adding verbiage to the error messages explaining what type of error occurred in lieu of just saying "Invalid input".

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with your attempt, and I've explained those problems as comments in the code below:

```
o = "+","-","*","/","%"
# o is now defined as a tuple containing all the allowed operators

x = input("Enter a math problem: ")

if " " in x:
  print("Invalid input")
  # You print "Invalid input" but then you continue to do the next steps. 
  # There should be an else here like below:
# else:
  try: 
    num1,o,num2 = x.split()
    # split() splits on whitespace, which your input doesn't have
    # You also overwrite o
  except ValueError: # split doesn't throw a valueerror
    print("Invalid Input")

    # This try..except block needs to be un-indented out of the previous except
    try: 
      num1 = int(num1)
      num2 = int(num2)
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid Input")

    # o HAS to be in x because you got it by splitting x (if the split() was correct)
    if o not in x:
      print("Invalid Input")

if o == "+":
  r = int(num1) + int(num2)
elif o == "-":
  r = int(num1) - int(num2)
elif o == "*":
  r = int(num1) * int(num2)
elif o == "/":
  r = int(num1) / int(num2)
elif o == "%":
  r = int(num1) % int(num2)
  # this print is in the elif o == '%' block, so something will only be printed when you try to do a mod operation
  print("Result is", r)
```

---

Consider this approach:

- If there are any spaces in the input, we print `"Invalid input"`.
- We iterate over the string looking for an operator.
- When we find an operator, we designate the part before it as `num1` and the part after it as `num2`.
- We try to convert `num1` and `num2` to integers. If there are decimals or any non-numbers, an error is thrown. We catch this error to print `"Invalid input"`
- Finally, if we haven't encountered an error yet, we calculate and print the result

Note my use of descriptive variable names, which make the code more readable.

```
operators = ("+", "-", "*", "/", "%")

user_input = input("Enter a math problem: ")

if " " in user_input:
    print("Invalid input")
else:
    op_index = -1
    for i, char in enumerate(user_input):
        if char in operators:
            op_index = i
            break # We found an operator, so we don't need to look further

    if op_index == -1:
        # op_index is still -1, so no operator was found
        print("Invalid input")
    else:
        try:
            num1 = int(user_input[:op_index]) # Slice the user input from the start until the character before the operator for num1
            num2 = int(user_input[op_index+1:]) # Slice the user input from the character after the operator until the end for num2
            op = user_input[op_index] # The operator is what we found at op_index
            if op == "+": 
                result = num1 + num2
            elif op == "-": 
                result = num1 - num2
            elif op == "*": 
                result = num1 * num2
            elif op == "/": 
                result = num1 / num2
            elif op == "%": 
                result = num1 % num2
            print(f"Result is {result}")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

One crucial issue was the parsing with `split()`.

From presented answers I collected the good parts and improved some spots.

#### Good practice

1. separate UI (input incl. validation / output incl. formatting or error-response) from business-logic (calculation) - [Separations of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
2. use functions for separate responsibilities ([Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle))
3. validate first, fail-fast ([Guard statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29) like `if: raise` or `if: return`)
4. give the user a chance to fix their input errors (here: retry-loop) as recommended by [User Journeys: UX Guidelines for Error Handling](https://www.userjourneys.com/blog/ux-guidelines-for-error-handling/)
5. test and mention edge-cases like negative numbers or minimum input (see [docstring](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/))
6. use `split(sep=operator)` with explicit separator like '+', since without arguments [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) would use space as implicit default which is not allowed

#### Example using functions, improved error-handling, and split-by-operator

```py
def read_math_problem():
    """
    Reads a single-line input from STDIN in the form of <number><operator><number> (without spaces).
    <number>: must be a positive integer like 0, 1 or 1234 (no decimal, no thousand-separators).
    <operator>: one of the 5 symbols +,-,*,/ for basic arithmetics or % for modulo.
    
    Valid Examples:
    1+2
    1234%10
    Invalid Examples:
    1 + 2
    1,5*2
    -5+10
    1.000/500
    2^8
    
    Returns a tuple of (integer1, operator, integer2).
    If the input is invalid, a ValueError is raised with details and explaining how to fix it.
    """
    x = input("Enter a math problem: ")

    # basic validation: minimum length and valid characters
    if len(x) < 3:
        raise ValueError(f"Was '{x}' but must be at least 3 characters long, like in 0+0. Please add required input.")
    if " " in x:
        raise ValueError(f"'{x}' contains spaces, please remove them.")

    # syntactic validation: valid operator required (also for parsing by split)
    operators = "+", "-", "*", "/", "%"
    operator = None
    for o in operators:
        if o in x:
            operator = o
            print("INFO: Found valid operator:", operator)
            break;
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"'{x}' must contain one of these operators: {operators}")
    
    # syntactic validation: requires two operands on each side of the operator
    try:
        num1, num2 = x.split(sep=operator)
    except ValueError as e:  # e.g. 0--2 raises ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
        raise ValueError(f"'{x}' has valid operator '{operator}' but has either more or less than additionally required 2 numbers. Valid example: 1{operator}2.")
    
    # semantic validation: operands (numbers) must be positive integers 
    try: 
        num1 = int(num1)
        num2 = int(num2)
        if num1 < 0 or num2 < 0:
            raise ValueError("Only positive integer numbers supported.")
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError(f"Make sure both '{num1}' and '{num2}' are positive integer numbers without separators.")
    
    return (num1, operator, num2)


def solve_math_problem(num1, operator, num2):
    if operator == "+":
        return num1 + num2
    elif operator == "-":
        return num1 - num2
    elif operator == "*":
        return  num1 * num2
    elif operator == "/":
        return num1 / num2
    elif operator == "%":
        return num1 % num2
    
    # else: operator was not implemented
    valid_operators = ("+", "-", "*", "/", "%")
    raise ValueError(f"Operator '{operator}' not supported. Please use one of these: {valid_operators}.")


math_tuple = None
while not math_tuple:  # Retry-Loop: let the user retry until input is valid
    try:
        math_tuple = read_math_problem()
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Invalid Input:", e)

# Happy Path: we have a valid problem to solve
result = solve_math_problem(*math_tuple)  # unpack the tuple to 3 separate arguments
print("Result is:", result)
```

#### To be improved

What's left for the next iteration to improve:

- **Naming**: The function names are on a very abstract level (`math_problem` is are rather vague `math_tuple`). What can describe the input better? Something like "Simple [Arithmetic Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(mathematics))".
- **Design**: The tuple assigned from result and its unpacking with `*` in the function call are not very expressive when reading just the two lines. A well-designed parser usually returns an object-model. But that would require advanced skills in Python like [object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and defining classes.
- **UI/UX**: A good user-interface tells the user upfront what task they can solve and which input (in which form) is expected, maybe with examples. Plus, there should always be a way to abort, cancel or exit. Ask for the no-spaces requirement, consider to just allow spaces and trim or sanitize them before parsing. This would be [Error-tolerant design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-tolerant_design) and applies the UX design-principle [forgiveness](https://uxplanet.org/design-principle-error-forgiveness-1495f7471113), similar to the [tolerant-reader pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html) in web-service design.
- **Maintainability/Extensibility:** See how the supported functionality (given by valid and implemented *operators*) is hard-coded at least 3 different places (internal doc-string, functions and output-messages). This means when changing, adding or removing one, we need to touch more than one place. Maybe a dictionary with lambdas could help here (like on Code Review Stack Exchange: [Expression calculator in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190101/expression-calculator-in-python)), or classes when learning OOP.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
x = input("Enter a math problem: ")

try:
  num1,o,num2 = x.split(" ")
except: 
  print("Invalid Input")
  exit()
try:
  num1 = int(num1)
  num2 = int(num2)
except:
  print("Invalid Input")
  exit()
if o not in x:
  print("Invalid Input")
  exit()

if o == "+":
  r = int(num1) + int(num2)
elif o == "-":
  r = int(num1) - int(num2)
elif o == "*":
  r = int(num1) * int(num2)
elif o == "/":
  r = int(num1) / int(num2)
elif o == "%":
  r = int(num1) % int(num2)
print("Result is", r)
```

I made some small changes:

1. You don't need to define `o` from the beginning of the code, so I erased the first line.
2. To define the variables `num1`, `o` and `num2` using `split()`, the numbers and the symbol between them must have something that separates them (like a space or another symbol).
   So you must include spaces between each character if you want it this way. Like `4 + 5` or `10 / 2`.
3. (I also erased some spaces)

If it must work without spaces, you can't use `split()`.

Like this:

```
x = input("Enter a math problem: ")

if " " in x:
  print("Invalid input")
  exit()
try:
  num1,o,num2 = x[0],x[1],x[2] #You get the 1st, 2nd and 3rd characters of "x" and store them as "num1", "o" and "num2"
except: 
  print("Invalid Input")
  exit()
try:
  num1 = int(num1)
  num2 = int(num2)
except:
  print("Invalid Input")
  exit()
if o not in x:
  print("Invalid Input")
  exit()

if o == "+":
  r = int(num1) + int(num2)
elif o == "-":
  r = int(num1) - int(num2)
elif o == "*":
  r = int(num1) * int(num2)
elif o == "/":
  r = int(num1) / int(num2)
elif o == "%":
  r = int(num1) % int(num2)
print("Result is", r)
```

Comment: List the changes you made, and explain why, so a master teaches learners who ask.
Agree that [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by default uses (white)space characters as separator. But the requirement can be understood as spaces in input should fail as invalid.

Comment: You could explain _why_ `split` wont work when invoked with defaults (spaces). Explaining how split works may provide a better alternative than limiting to single-digit operands in 3-character input because `x[0], x[1], x[2]`. Example: `for o in operators: (num1, num2) = x.split(o)`

Comment: Why is this post "-2"? I have explained everything! Look at the one with "+1". What does he explain? @hc_dev

Comment: Certainly not this `split` issue, but solved it with the preparation-hack `x.replace(operator," ").split()`. Removed my downvote, because you explained: the split-mechanism requires a separator. But did you solve it? The answer might reflect in the other downvote. Your first solution requires spaces in input (not the question). The second uses indexing which is very inflexible for parsing because fixed width/position (0,1,2) allowing numbers 0..9 only. What about `1234+567`? BTW: I only upvoted one answer - for improved usability/error-handling as additional suggestion.